# Async with Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm newbie of Redux-saga. I have a project using Redux-saga, and this is my snip code:

```
// saga.js
function* FetchData() {
    try {
        const AppData = yield call(fetch_Data, "LOAD_APP", App_Url);
        yield put({ type: "LOAD_APP", data: AppData })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

function* watchFetchAPI() {
         yield takeEvery("LOAD_ASYNC", FetchData)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        watchFetchAPI()
    ])
}

// action.js
export function fetch_Data(type, url) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        contentType: 'json'
    }).then(function (res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            console.log("Failed. type: " + type + " Url: " + url);
        }
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log("Failed. type: " + type + " Url: " + url);
        console.log(e)
    })
}
```

In my component dispatch action :

> this.props.dispatch({ type: "LOAD_ASYNC"})}

And reducers :

```
  // pageReducer.js

    export function calc(state = [], action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "LOAD_APP":
                return [{ type: action.type, data: action.data }]
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

// rootReducer.js
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
    import { calc } from './pageReducers'
    const Rootreducers = combineReducers(
        {
            data: calc
        }
    )
    export default Rootreducers
```

I don't get data before page re-render. I'm debug and see my api fetch return data after my page re-render , so in store data is undefined . How to resolve this ?

Comment: can you share your reducer LOAD_APP ?

Comment: Hi @Umesh. this my reducer : export function calc(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOAD_APP":
            return [{ type: action.type, data: action.data }]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { calc } from './pageReducers'


const Rootreducers = combineReducers(
    {
        data: calc
    }
)
export default Rootreducers

Comment: can you show the component code?

Comment: @stack26 . i just have a button : <button onClick={() => {this.props.dispatch({ type: "LOAD_ASYNC"})}} >FETCH</button> and map state function: function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.data
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

Comment: You should either use defaultProps in your component so it can use when you don't have any data or have an initial state in your reducer that has the structure of your data. Have a look at this https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/admin/src/containers/EditPage/reducer.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch_Data` didn't return fetch result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `fetch_Data`. You should return the Promise returned by `fetch` like so:

```
// action.js
export function fetch_Data(type, url) {
  return fetch(...).then(...).catch(...)
}
```

Your `yield call(fetch_Data, ...)` statement will only block if a promise is returned. Because the fetch promise is not returned, `FetchData` continues on with execution and `AppData` will be undefined.
By returning the promise, `FetchData` will block until the promise resolved or rejected and AppData or catch will work as expected.